# d3.js drawing two lines within an element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I use the D3.js JavaScript library to draw charts. I want to draw two charts in svg, inside the `<g>` tag. My html looks like this:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 970 580">
  <g style="transform: translate(40px, 20px);" class="stage">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Charts should be defined by `<path>`element with the `line` attribute. My data array is a nested array:

```
const data = [[{x: 1, y: 3.4}, ...], [{x: 1, y: 4.3}, ...]]
```

To draw lines, i use following algorithm: select DOM element `<g >` with class `stage` and append `<path>` element with `line` attribute. My code looks like this:

```
const $stage = d3.select('.stage')
const line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBasis).x(d => scale.x(d.x)).y(d => scale.y(d.y))

for (chartData of data) {
    const $line = $stage.selectAll('path').data(chartData)

    $line.enter().attr('d', line).style('fill', 'none').style('stroke-width', 2)
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuf1emtr/1/)

But when I run it I get an error: `TypeError: this.removeAttribute is not a function`. This is a standard code pattern for draw chart, can't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm reading correctly you are trying to do something like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955. You are also not using `.append('line')` after your enter statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For updating charts Mike Bostock has a 3 part series about the [General Update Pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). I have linked part 1.

As for your chart I [made some updates to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avs56frb/).

As you can see I added

```
  .append('path')
```

into your `.enter()` statement to give this:

```
$line
 .enter()
 .append('path')
 .attr('d', line)
 .style('fill', 'none')
 .style('stroke', 'black')
 .style('stroke-width', 2);
```

The append statement is important as it is what d3 should be appending each time it sees a new data set. I also added a `stroke` colour so that the lines are visible.

When adding lines in d3 it is not required that you loop over the array and add a line per index. d3 will handle the looping for you and will append a new line per array index.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to be able to set certain colors for charts? That is, if for example an array of data has the form: `const data = [{color: '#fff', points: [{x: 1, y: 3.4}, ...]}, {color: '#777', points: [{x: 1, y: 4.3}, ...]}]` ?

Comment: The easiest way is to set an colours array which you then access via index http://jsfiddle.net/avs56frb/1/ I updated the fiddle to demonstrate.